# What is the Promise.all equivalent in Observables?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, rxjs, observable

I am trying to loop through array of observables and want the result of subscription in an array under single subscription.

Comment: You can sort it out yourself using this snazzy tool: http://rxmarbles.com/

Comment: why not post what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of Promise.all is [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).